# Robotframework DatafileError when launching docker container trough Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, robotframework

When launching a pipeline using Jenkins with the following syntax:

```
    stage('Verify test') {
        agent {
            docker { image 'python_image:latest' }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'robot RobotFramework/test.robot'                
        }
        post {
            always {
                archiveArtifacts 'log.html'
                archiveArtifacts 'report.html'
                archiveArtifacts 'output.xml'
                junit 'output.xml'
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the following error:

connect to UUT device                                                 | FAIL |

DatafileError: Failed to load the datafile '/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/genie/libs/sdk/genie_yamls/iosxr/trigger_datafile_xr.yaml'

It does work when I try the exact same command (robot RobotFramework/test.robot) on a new Docker container using the same image or when I pause the container in the Jenkins pipeline and execute the exact same command on the running container

Only when I am creating a virtual env on the docker container I get the exact same error but I assume that that is not happening when running a Docker container with Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding #!/bin/bash

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash robot RobotFramework/test.robot'''
```